# Extract all values in a string that occur after another substring in R

Tags: r, regex, parsing, substring

Lets say I have a string:

```
fgjh=621729_&ioij_fgjh7=twenty-_-One-_-Forty
```

I want to extract the following substrings from this string:

```
1. "621729"
2. "twenty"
3. "One"
4. "Forty"
```

Basically I want to extract anything after the "fgjh=" substring and "fgjh7=" sub strings.

I've found that this formula works in excel:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"fgjh=",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

But the excel file is too large and I need to perform the same operation in R

How would I deal with leading characters and trailing characters. Let's say the string was "lmnop_82137_hhgia=77789_pasdk_ikuk_fgjh=621729_&ioij_fgjh7=‌​twenty--One--Forty_d‌​saoij_882390=lkuk" and I need to extract the data after "fgjh=" i.e 621729 and everything after "fgjh7=" to get only "twenty", "one" and "forty"

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub` with regular expression is more flexible than splitting by position:

```
> sub(".*=(.*)_&.*", "\\1", "fgjh=621729_&ioij_fgjh7=twenty--One--Forty", )
[1] "621729"
> sub(".*=(.*)--.*--.*", "\\1", "fgjh=621729_&ioij_fgjh7=twenty--One--Forty", )
[1] "twenty"
> sub(".*--(.*)--.*", "\\1", "fgjh=621729_&ioij_fgjh7=twenty--One--Forty", )
[1] "One"
> sub(".*--(.*)$", "\\1", "fgjh=621729_&ioij_fgjh7=twenty--One--Forty", )
[1] "Forty"
```

In one line :

```
strsplit(sub(".*=(.*)_&.*=(.*)--(.*)--(.*)", "\\1\\|\\2\\|\\3\\|\\4", 
  "fgjh=621729_&ioij_fgjh7=twenty--One--Forty" ), split="\\|")[[1]]

[1] "621729" "twenty" "One"    "Forty"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package `stringr` and the function `str_match` for example to parse out the interesting bits with regular expressions

```
> library(stringr)
> s <- "fgjh=621729_&ioij_fgjh7=twenty--One--Forty"

> str_match(s, "^fgjh=([0-9]+)_&ioij_fgjh7=(.+)--(.+)--(.+)$")
     [,1]                                         [,2]     [,3]     [,4]  [,5]   
[1,] "fgjh=621729_&ioij_fgjh7=twenty--One--Forty" "621729" "twenty" "One" "Forty"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
unlist(strsplit(str_extract_all(string,'(?<=\\=)([^_]+)')[[1]],'--'))
[1] "621729" "twenty" "One"    "Forty"
```